# How to call a procedure depending on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

Please Help,

I have written different procedures on different worksheet in a Workbook. I want to call a particular procedure depending on the specific cell value in a worksheet.

I tried with defining a variable

Example:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
pbk = Me.Range("L1").Value
Call pbk
End Sub
```

but I'm getting errors like this:

```
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications
Compile error:
Expected Sub, Function, or Property
```

value Range L1 is changing as per contents it has array of total 15 contents, so I have written 15 procedures different. i just need to call each procedure depending on the value of 'L1'.

Its total 15 Procedures, i can write with the IF condition like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
pbk = Me.Range("L1").Value
If pbk = "PBK_Kirim" Then
Call PBK_Kirim
End If
If pbk = "PBK_ke_Masa" Then
Call PBK_ke_Masa
End If
'and so on
End Sub
```

but it will be too bulky so i'm trying for some easy method. thanks before

Comment: Use `Application.Run` not `Call`

Comment: How are PBK_Kirim and PBK_Ke_Masa different? No chance to have a generic routine that gets "Kirim"or "ke_masa" as a parameter? (I am asking because I have seen code that has been duplicated multiple times instead of using parameters - and then called exactly like you are describing it)

Comment: `CallByName` if it's an object method.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rory, use "run pbk". Only other alternative to clean it up without using run that I can think of is build another sub routine passing in the pbk value and using select case for the different calls.